# How to count the number of manytomany in a template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a generic template rendering of a form, and I want to do something like:

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}">
        {{ field.label }}
    </label>
    {% if field.checked_count==0 %}
        {% trans "nothing checked" %}
    {% elif field.checked_count==1 %}
        {% trans "one checked" %}
    {% else %}
        {% trans "many checked" %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

As you can imagine, the `field.checked_count` doesn't work. Knowing that I will display only manytomany fields, is there a generic way to know how many of those items are checked?

Comment: Add the code of your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shoud be something like

```
{% if field.checked_count.all.count==0 %}
```

Comment: simply doing {% if field.checked.all.count==0 %} worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Hey for someone who is here and has the same problem that i had, i fixed my problem using this in my template

```
{{ field.atribute.all.count }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{{ field.field.choices|length }}` to get the number of choices on that field.